# Encrypt Voice over GSM in android

Tags: android, encryption, voice

Is it possible to perform encryption and decryption on Voice call over gsm in android on Application level or Android OS level?

Comment: Definitely not at the application level.

Comment: https://mocana.com/keytone/

Answer (score 0):

Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716097/how-to-implement-voice-changer-in-android-during-phone-call
Sadly, I think, it is impossible without rooting/advanced modification of system.